# Variadic template: lvalue vs rvalue references

Tags: c++

The following code compiles with c++11 or higher

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

#define p 1

// p1: prototype 1
template <class Function, class... Args>
void addv(Function&& f, Args&... args) {
  std::cout << f(args...) << std::endl;
}
// p2: prototype 2
template <class Function, class... Args>
void addv(Function& f, Args&... args) {
  std::cout << f(args...) << std::endl;
}

int add(int& a, int& b) {
  return a+b;
}

class Adder {
  public:
    int operator () (int& a, int&b) {
      return a+b;
    }
};

int main() {
  int a = 2;
  int b = 1;
  Adder adder;

  addv<int (int&,int&),int,int>(add,a,b); // uses p1 OR p2
  addv<Adder,int,int>(Adder(),a,b); // uses p1
  addv<Adder,int,int>(adder,a,b); // uses p2

}
```

If prototype 2 is removed, and this is compiled, the following error happens:

```
exp.cpp:36:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘addv<Adder, int, int>(Adder&, int&, int&)’
       addv<Adder,int,int>(adder,a,b); // uses p2
                                    ^
exp.cpp:9:10: note: candidate: template<class Function, class ... Args> void addv(Function&&, Args& ...)
     void addv(Function&& f, Args&... args) {
          ^~~~
exp.cpp:9:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
exp.cpp:36:36: note:   cannot convert ‘adder’ (type ‘Adder’) to type ‘Adder&&’
       addv<Adder,int,int>(adder,a,b); // uses p2
                                    ^
```

Why `adder` cannot be converted from a lvalue to a rvalue implicitly as is needed to have the line `addv<Adder,int,int>(adder,a,b);` use prototype 1?

Is it possible to explicitly create a rvalue reference of `adder` to have it correctly match prototype 1?

Comment: Just remove the explicitly specified parameters and the compiler will do ok with just protorype 1. `addv(adder,a,b);`

Comment: With your explicit instantiation of the function template, you are asking it to bind an lval-ref to an rval-ref - and that is not allowed.  In general, you should not use function templates in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be converted because the idea with using rvalue and lvalue references in function signatures is exactly to make sure you get one or the other. Not either one.

Normally that is used because if you get an rvalue, you can move it. If you get an lvalue you need to copy it. You can also make sure that a function is only callable with an rvalue, or lvalue.

When passing functions the usual way is to take the parameter by value. That also works with both rvalues and lvalues. This is how it's (almost always?) done in the standard library. Function pointers and Functors are generally very cheap to copy.

If you want a signature that can take both rvalues and lvalues you can use `const &`.

Also note that since `Function&&` is a template parameter, it is a forwarding reference. Thats means it will become an rvalue reference or lvalue reference depending on what you pass in.

When you call the function with an explicitly specified parameter though

```
addv<Adder,int,int>(adder,a,b);
       ^--this
```

the template parameter will be deduced to exactly `Adder`, and your function will then accept only rvalues, since the signature says `Function&& -> Adder&&`.

The easy way to make the code work is to not explicitly specify the template parameter.

```
addv(adder,a,b);
```

Then you can remove prototype 2 and all the function calls will work.

If you really want to or need to specify the parameters, you can use `std::move` to convert an lvalue to an rvalue at the calling site.

```
addv<Adder,int,int>(std::move(adder),a,b);
```

**Edit:** Convert might be a bit misleading. It's actually a cast. Nothing is changed except the value category.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will compile if you don't explicitly specify template parameters and let template type deduction work it out:

```
addv(Adder(),a,b); // this is deduced to 
                   // addv<Adder, int, int>(Adder&&, int&, int&)

addv(adder,a,b); // this is deduced to 
                 // addv<Adder&, int, int>(Adder& &&, int&, int&),
                 // which becomes addv<Adder&, int,int>(Adder&, int&, int&)
                 // after reference collapsing
```

So you do want to explicitly specify template parameter, it needs to be

```
addv<Adder&, int,int>(adder,a,b);
```

Have a look at Scott Meyers' excellent article on [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) (and in particular '**reference collapsing**'), hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article, I found that very helpful.